# How to get internal group inside regex or operation

Tags: java, regex

I was trying to solve a regex problem but not getting the solution.

```
String sample1 = "Hello234Water";

String sample2 = "Hello254World";


String pat1 = "Hello(\\d+)World";

String pat2 = "Hello(\\d+)Water";


String pat = "(Hello(\\d+)World|Hello(\\d+)Water)";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pat, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(sample1);
if (m.find()) {
    String int1 = m.group(1);
    System.out.print(int1);

}
```

expected response `234` but getting `Hello234Water`

---

**EDIT 1:**

I was trying to solve a regex problem but not getting the solution.

```
    String sample1 = "Hot234Water";

    String sample2 = "Hello254World";


    String pat1 = "Hello(\\d+)World";

    String pat2 = "Hot(\\d+)Water";


    String pat = "(Hello(\\d+)World|Hot(\\d+)Water)";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pat, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(sample1);
    if (m.find()) {
        String int1 = m.group(1);
        System.out.print(int1);

    }
```

expected response **234** but getting **Hot234Water**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have unnecessary group and also you need to use alternation at right place:

```
String pat = "Hello(\\d+)(?:World|Water)";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pat, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Moreover you don't need `DOTALL` mode since you are not matching anything across newlines using `.` (DOT).

fyi `(?:...)` is called non-capturing group.

---

For your **edited problem** you can use this regex:

```
final String pat = "^(?=Hello\\d+World$|Hot\\d+Water$)\\D+(\\d+)";
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uHhj1C/1)

Comment: i have updated the pattern,  content of both the side of group is different.

Comment: I need to get numeric value from both the string Hot234Water  and Hello254World with the help of m.group(1). considering the fact that both the numbers are covered with different text on left and right side.

Comment: You have totally changed nature of problem now :)

Comment: yes exactly this was the problem, i just tried to recreate the same via sample code and i missed that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like [this](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html) to see what group you should be accessing.  It's very convenient!

In this case you have a total of 4 groups:

1. The entire matched expression
2. (Hello(\d+)World|Hello(\d+)Water) which resolves to Hello234Water
3. The first (\d+), which is empty
4. The last (\d+), which contains your desired value.

My recommendation is to simplify the Regex as others have suggested.